# "Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider" error when Keycloak broker is configured as a client to another Keycloak instance

Tags: keycloak

I am getting an error when I try to login to Keycloak by using it as a broker.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv1MA.png) I am using credentials from another keycloak instance to login. So far, I am redirected to the correct login page but after entering my credentials I receive an error.

I have set up Keycloack Identity Brokering on computer 1 by following the basic steps.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBZDB.png) I have used the generated redirection URI of the broker to register a new client on computer 2 in another Keycloak instance.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcWTy.jpg) The client configuration present on computer 2 [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwMEw.jpg) is then used to fill in Authorization URL, Token URL, Client ID and Client Secret on the Identity Broker on Computer 1. [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAGGr.jpg)

I may be leaving important fields missing. Pictures are attached for reference.

Answer (score 4):

I have changed some settings to get the broker to work with the other Keycloak instance. I am now sending client secret as basic auth with signed verification off. I have also enabled back-channel logout. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: back-channel logout solved that issue for me too thx so much!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by regenerating the client secret on the identity provider side and using it on keycloak. The keycloak realm data import was not working very well for me apparently.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to empty the hosted domain field in the "Identity providers" configuration of my Google identity provider in Keycloak.

See also:
[Keycloak Google identity provider error: "Identity token does not contain hosted domain parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65144432/keycloak-google-identity-provider-error-identity-token-does-not-contain-hosted)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Stefan, i just reset the client secret though on the Keycloak side - so didnt have to reconfigure the client in all other instances, just on the newly created/imported one.